# Redirect POST htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, forms

This question is very similar to: [Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data) (asked eariler) but that answer does not seem to work for me.

I have a form:

```
<form action="http://a.test.com/contact" name="contact" method="post">
```

and inside of a add-on domain, (test.com is an addon), there is a subdomain (a.), and inside of there I have a file item.php, and .htaccess

my htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#normal rewrites
RewriteRule ^[~|-]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]*$ item.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

note: I left it as [NC,L] because when I changed it to [NC,P] it gives me a 500 server error.

and my item.php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

and no matter what the form contains, the $_POST is blank... however, if I do http://a.test.com/item.php?user=contact as the action.

all goes well. POSTing skips the htaccess, and the solution on SO doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you **redirect** client then? Remove your redirect rule (or just remove redirect flag), if you don't want to redirect, thus lose the POST data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess - Is it possible to redirect post data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your "add trailing slash" rule forces a header redirect:

```
 [R=301,L]
```

a header redirect will drop POST values.

You will have to drop that rule, or disable it for POST submissions:

```
# Forces a trailing slash to be added

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I often see that people use only regex-based comparisons, but not string-based: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST`. Why? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms fair point :) To be honest, I wasn't even aware that notation was possible. Thanks, fixed