# .htaccess and forwarding the GET/POST parameters in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with .htaccess not forwarding the GET/POST parameters..

Here's my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?a=%1&b=%2 [L]
```

But when I do something like :

```
mywebsite.com/url1/url2?action=delete&id=2
```

It redirects me to :

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?a=url1&b=url2
```

so it deletes the **action=delete&id=2** and I have nothing in $_GET, is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how should be the query after `index.php`?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638678/redirect-post-htaccess) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QSA` (as in Query String Append)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?a=%1&b=%2 [L,QSA]
```