# PHP Rest API, Redirect POST router

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, rest

I am attempting to write a simple RESTful php application.  I am attempting to write a single index.php router.

The .htaccess file I currently have is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule api/^(.*)$ api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$` to force a trailing slash as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638678/redirect-post-htaccess).

Calling `var_dump($_POST);` or `var_dump($_GET);` still returns an empty array, POST values are still being dropped.  Sending a GET and a POST both returns a GET when evaluating: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`.

How do I implement this correctly? Also, I cannot use a library and must implement my own router.

Any assistance or advice appreciated.

---

> EDIT:

---

Started over from scratch:

Url for requests should be `http://localhost/api/*`

Current .htaccess file located in the api folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

where `controller.php` is sitting in `/var/www/api`

Vhost file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

is titled *api.conf*

and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api/
    <Directory "/var/www/api/">
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Still having the same problem:

```
The requested URL /api/something was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

Apache overwrote the `default.conf` file in the sites-available folder when I performed an update which I overlooked...

I needed to add to `000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     AllowOverride All
```

I discovered mod_rewrite was now off:

```
in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
//or
var_dump(apache_get_modules());
```

so to reenable:

```
a2enmod rewrite

service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps others.