# Passing variable through subdomain wildcard redirect?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I am working on a new script that basically instead when somebody searches for something on my website how it normally goes to here:

http://domain.com/index.php?q=apples

to

http://apples.domain.com

I have made this work perfectly in PHP as well as htaccess but the problem I am having is using the original keyword afterwards on the new subdomain page.

Right now I can use parse_url to get the keyword out of the url but my script also filters out potential problems like:

```
public function sanitise($v, $separator = '-')
    {
        return trim(
            preg_replace('#[^\w\-]+#', $separator, $v),
            $separator
        );
    }
```

So if somebody searches for netbook v1.2

The new subdomain would be:

http://netbook-v1-2.domain.com

Now I can take the keyword out but it's with the dashes and not original. I am looking for a way to send over the original keyword with the 301 redirect as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either just replace the hyphen with spaces when they visit the new subdomain or, since you're on the same top-level domain, you can just cookie the keyword when redirecting them:

```
setcookie('clientkeyword', 'netbook-v1-2.domain.com:netbook v1.2', 0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

Comment: Works great when people are searching for the item themselves, but if a user clicks on apples.domain.com from google or something, nothing would show. :(

Comment: That's why I also stated `just replace the hyphen with spaces` from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. There's nothing else you can do in that case.

Comment: After thinking about it, you are absolutely right. There is nothing else I can do about it so this should be good enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/358334/992437

And see if you can use the POST or GET data that's already there.  If so, that might be your best bet.

Comment: That specific flag in the .htaccess tells the POST data and GET data to be redirected as well.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You're confusing rewrite with redirect. The client will not repost its data.

Comment: I must be completely confused.  But from my experience, RewriteRule's can redirect as well ([L,R=301]).  That's part of what they do.  I'll look into this more though, as I might have missed something.