# paypal sandbox IPN notification url not responding

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am implement Paypal standard payment in my site. I have a resource to receive notification when user issue a subscription and update data base in-order to tracking the sale and user payment. I do accidentally change the notification resource on my site which mean making it stop working. Is there any setting with paypal to alert me by email once user successful check out and notification url stop working?

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed your notification URL, as far as I know, there's no way to change the URL stored in any previously created transaction (excepting, of course, those transactions created without a URL that default to the IPN URL specified in your Profile settings).

Your best bet is to keep the previous listener alive and forward it if necessary. Establishing a 301 redirect from the old URL to the new one that preserves the POSTed IPN data may be a possible solution based on the answer to this question: [.htaccess - Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)

Comment: I was wonder why when the notification url goes down or stop responding paypal service doesn't send me any alert example via email or something.

Comment: You actually can see your IPN history in your account settings, so even though they don't e-mail you they will display a list of successful vs. failed IPNs. It's in the History drop down menu from your PayPal account front page.

Answer (score 0):

You actually will get a notification from PayPal if the IPN url is unresponsive. The email looks like this:

```
 Hello xxxxx,

 Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN).
 IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

    http://domain.com/ipnhandler.php

 If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is
 using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above
 information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account.

 Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.


 Thanks,

 PayPal
```

In our case, the processing scheme knows that IPNs are outstanding (we also have a reconciliation step each morning), so we could look if we had to - but I don't understand why you're having "an accident".

Comment: Jimzie, I'm testing a use-case for the app. Actually I testing with paypal sandbox it doesn't give me any alert. What's environment are you working with?

Comment: Oh, that was the Production environment. You don't get the alert in the Sandbox (I would have gotten plenty over the years!)