# .htaccess RewriteRule - matching patterns & forwarding posts

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rule that maintains legacy urls with a rule that matches a pattern but I would like to add something that redirects url posts as well.  I'm not good a this htaccess stuff.  Here is a scenario:

Legacy URL:

```
www.blah.com/register/player
```

Legacy RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)/?$ /account/register.php?type=$1 [NC,L]
```

New URL:

```
www.blah.com/register/player?email=bob@g.com
```

New RewriteRule???

```
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)/?$ /account/register.php?type=$1 [NC,P]
```

I found this post [Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263) that helped me find the P flag which works without the pattern match but it doesn't work when I try to do both.

I don't want to just add another pattern match because my url post data can be arbitrary with more then one param (the case described above is simplified). It seems like this should be doable. Is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need the query string attached on redirect, hence the QSA flag

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)/?$ /account/register.php?type=$1 [QSA,NC,P]
```

Comment: That's works! I didn't know about that flag. Thank you very much.  Here is a link for future folks http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: I don't think you really need the `[P]`, because you are only after the GET data, and POST will be handled anyway.  
Try replacing the `[P]` with an `[L]`, denoting the last rewrite rule in this rewrite condition.