# PHP POST to RESTful API implemented with apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a PHP RESTful API following [this example](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) (code at the bottom). From what I understand, the API converts non-existing URI components to GET parameters in the address via the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

So if I do, e.g.:

```
http://mysite/api/v1/endpoint1/param1
```

`endpoint1/param1` can be parsed in the API implementation to call a PHP function `endpoint1(param1)`.

Now my issue is, param1 is really long, and I want use AJAX to `POST` `param1`, but the POST doesn't go through

For example, for the RESTful API:

```
http://mysite/api/v1/endpoint1
```

I POSTed `data` using AJAX as follows:

```
$.post('http://mysite/api/v1/endpoint1/',data,callback,'json');
```

In `API.class.php`, `$_SERVER['REQEUEST_METHOD']` is `'POST'`, but `$_POST` is empty array.

My questions are:

What is actually happening when I `POST` to a virtual URL to be handled by `mod_rewrite`. Is the end result a `GET` request by `mode_rewrite` or a `POST` request by my AJAX call?

How can I modify the code to get the `POST`ed data through? (Is it possible to ask mod_rewrite to use the POST method instead?)

I am confused here, any pointers are appreciated.

---

The interface for the relevant REST api is (`API.class.php`, please see [the example](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) for complete code):

```
<?php
abstract class API
{
    protected $method = '';
    protected $endpoint = '';
    protected $args = Array();
    protected $file = Null;
    public function __construct($request) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        $this->args = explode('/', rtrim($request, '/'));
        $this->endpoint = array_shift($this->args);
        $this->method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($this->method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
            if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
                $this->method = 'DELETE';
            } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
                $this->method = 'PUT';
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
            }
        }
        switch($this->method) {
        case 'DELETE':
        case 'POST':
            $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_POST);
            $this->args[] = ???; //Problem line: how do I add post to the args 
            break;
        case 'GET':
            $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_GET);
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            $this->request = $this->_cleanInputs($_GET);
            $this->file = file_get_contents("php://input");
            break;
        default:
            $this->_response('Invalid Method', 405);
            break;
        }
    }
    public function processAPI() {
        if ((int)method_exists($this, $this->endpoint) > 0) {
            return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
        }
        return $this->_response("No Endpoint: $this->endpoint", 404);
    }
    private function _response($data, $status = 200) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 " . $status . " " . $this->_requestStatus($status));
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    private function _cleanInputs($data) {
        $clean_input = Array();
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                $clean_input[$k] = $this->_cleanInputs($v);
            }
        } else {
            $clean_input = trim(strip_tags($data));
        }
        return $clean_input;
    }
    private function _requestStatus($code) {
        $status = array(  
            200 => 'OK',
            404 => 'Not Found',   
            405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
            500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        ); 
        return ($status[$code])?$status[$code]:$status[500]; 
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the issue you are running into:
[Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)

You should change this line in your .htaccess file from:
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

to:
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,P]

Comment: Thanks for the help. But after changing to [QSA, NC, P], the [QSA] (name capture??) part seems to stop working. Entering `http://mysite/api/v1/a` now gives `The requested URL /var/www.../api/v1/api.php was not found on this server`.