# Form in PHP and Bootstrap is not passing variables , is just following the path of action

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is the HTML code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="http://ead.montepage.com.br/login" id="loginbar" name="loginbar">
      <input type="hidden" name="postado" value="971519838881353a18b7069f3f8d40e8" />
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Acessar">Acessar</button>
      </form>
```

This is the PHP code, on the action file:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST['postado']))
        require_once('action_post.php');
?>
```

The form is on top of the url:
http://www.ead.montepage.com.br/

I do not know what 's going on, already googled and found nothing similar

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redirect setup, to redirect from non `www` to `www` url.
This redirect is causing post data to be lost.

Change your action to:

```
action="http://www.ead.montepage.com.br/login"
```

as a tempory fix, then fix your rewrite rule to send the post data:

[Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/htaccess-is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)

Comment: Just that the server is redirecting to " www". Thank you.