# How to send parameters when redirect happens by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to change my url to remove .php from url.

for example to change:
    www.example.com/insert.php to www.example.com/insert
but when  it happens the posted parameters doesn't exist in redirected request.
"i'm using post method to send data to insert.php"
How to solve this issue?

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Parameters needs to be added in url like www.example.com/insert/id instead of www.example.com/insert?id=123 , update your htaccess according to it

Comment: form's data that send to insert.php by post method

Comment: You *should* change the form action to `/insert` instead of `/insert.php`

Comment: I know that i can change forms action to "insert", but i want to know there is any way else.

Comment: first rewrite rule or second one?

Comment: Try this
`RewriteRule ^(\w+)\$ insert.php?id=$1`

Comment: Check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data

Comment: Lawrence Cherone ; it cuase error 500 in www.example.com.