# POST information getting lost in .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reference

So, I have a fully working CRUD. The problem is, because of my file structure, my URLs were looking something like *https://localhost/myapp/resources/views/add-product.php* but that looked too ugly, so after research and another post here, I was able to use a *.htaccess* file to make the links look like *https://localhost/myapp/add-product* (removing .php extension and the directories), and I'm also using it to enforce HTTPS. Now, most of the views are working fine, but my Mass Delete view uses POST information from a form on my index. After restructuring the code now that the redirect works, the Mass Delete view is receiving an empty array. If I remove the redirect and use the "ugly URLs" it works fine. Here's how my *.htaccess* file is looking like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/

RewriteRule ^resources/views/(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myapp/resources/views/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ resources/views/$1.php [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I didn't actually write any of it, it's a mesh between answered questions and research. I did try to change the **L** flag to a **P** according to this post: [Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data), but that gave me the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.2 Server at localhost Port 443
```

Comment: POST data is not preserved after redirect unless you use `R=307` or `R=308`. Older browsers may not support `307/308`

Comment: `R=307` worked! Thank you so much. Is there any downsides beside older browsers not having support?

Comment: No other downside that I am aware of

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for all of your help! :)

Comment: The downside would be that you are making the client send the full amount of POST data a second time. Why is your POST request not targeting the "pretty" URL in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> POST information getting lost in .htaccess redirect

You shouldn't be redirecting the form submission in the first place. Ideally, you should be linking directly to the "pretty" URL in your form `action`. If you are unable to change the form `action` in the HTML then include an exception in your `.htaccess` redirect to exclude this particular URL from being redirected.

Redirecting the form submission is not really helping anyone here. Users and search engines can still see the "ugly" URL (it's in the HTML source) and you are doubling the form submission that hits your server (and doubling the user's bandwidth).

"Redirects" like this are only for when search engines have already indexed the "ugly" URL and/or is linked to by external third parties that you have no control over. This is in order to preserve SEO, just like when you change any URL structure. All internal "ugly" URLs should have already been converted to the "pretty" version. The "ugly" URLs are then never exposed to users or search engines.

So, using a 307 (temporary) or 308 (permanent) status code to get the browser to *preserve* the request method across the redirect should not be necessary in the first place. For redirects like this it is common to see an exception for POST requests (because the form submission shouldn't be redirected). Or only target GET requests. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
:
```

Changing this redirect to a 307/8 is a *workaround*, not a solution. And if this redirect is for SEO (as it only should be) then this should be a 308 (permanent), not a 307 (temporary).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place. This needs to go as the *first* rule, or make sure you are redirecting to HTTPS in the current first rule and include this as the second rule, before the rewrite (to ensure you never get a double redirect).

By placing this rule last then any HTTP requests to `/resources/views/<something>.php` (or `/<something>`) will not be upgraded to HTTPS.