# RewriteRule giving Internal Server Error - trying to redirect POST requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am building a site that redirects all URLs to /src/routes.php. I am trying to use a 307 redirect to preserve POST data that is sent to the site.

When I put the following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /src/routes.php [QSA, L, R=307]
```

I get an Internal 500 Server Error. If I remove the `[QSA, L, R=307]`, the site redirects but POST data does not go through when trying to read from `php://input`.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Remove the spaces from your flags **[QSA,L,R=307]**

Comment: Although, even if you remove the _spaces_ (as @imvain2 suggests) - to resolve the 500 error - you will still get a redirect-loop, since you are redirecting "everything", including `/src/routes.php`!? Unless you have other directives that prevent this?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect at all? Why not an internal rewrite, which would not cause every request to get sent twice?

Comment: Not sure if you still need this after 10 months, but - please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/358334/), and also the comment by @marius .